# How to make custom Change Password redirect in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a site where a successful login redirects to a membership page:

```
_config.php
  Security::set_default_login_dest( '/join/' );
```

However when users go through the forgotten password/ change password process it behaves like this:

1. **/join/** - User starts at membership page
2. **/Security/lostpassword** - User clicks "forgotten password" link
3. **/Security/passwordsent/user%40example.com** - Password is sent to user
4. **/Security/changepassword?m=28&t=8dfeb7655db...** - User clicks password in email
5. **/Security/changepassword** - User is prompted to change password
6. **/Security/login?BackURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F** - User is redirected to login page

The expected behaviour for step 6 is the user is redirect to the default_login_dest - **/join/**

ChangePasswordForm.php has the following code controlling the location of the redirect:

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['BackURL'])) {
        $backURL = $_REQUEST['BackURL'];
    } else {
        $backURL = Session::get('BackURL');
    }
```

But CMSMemberLoginForm.php has this code:

```
    if (Security::config()->default_login_dest) {
        return $this->controller->redirect(Director::absoluteBaseURL() . Security::config()->default_login_dest);
    }
```

How do I make the ChangePasswordForm redirect to default_login_dest?

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but could you add a `&BackURL=...` to the e-mail template?

You can create a local copy of email templates `framework\templates\email\ForgotPasswordEmail.ss` and alter it to link to:

```
<a href="$PasswordResetLink&BackURL=/join/">
```